# How to strip pattern in the string?

Tags: python, string

I have below String.

```
a = "/root/LOAD/LOGS/2018-06-15_13:54/"
```

How can I get the output:

```
"/root/LOAD/LOGS/"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `os.path.dirname` to go up a directory as many times as you need to

```
>>> import os
>>> a = "/root/LOAD/LOGS/2018-06-15_13:54/"
>>> os.path.dirname(a)
'/root/LOAD/LOGS/2018-06-15_13:54'
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(a))
'/root/LOAD/LOGS'
```

This is easy to wrap in a helper function if you want to move up a known number of directories

```
def parent_dir(path, n):
    if n > 1:
        return parent_dir(os.path.dirname(path), n-1)
    return os.path.dirname(path)
```

Example

```
>>> parent_dir(a, 2)
'/root/LOAD/LOGS'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods, I would personally use the re (`import re`) module. But there is also the possibility to extract the directory without the additional module. It depends on whether you want to look at the slash (subdirectory) or the number of characters is enough (if the directory name does not change).

```
>>> a = "/root/LOAD/LOGS/2018-06-15_13:54/"    

>>> "/".join(a.split("/")[:-2])    # from right side
'/root/LOAD/LOGS'

>>> "/".join(a.split("/")[:4])     # from left side
'/root/LOAD/LOGS'

>>> a[:15]
'/root/LOAD/LOGS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths) module.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("/root/LOAD/LOGS/2018-06-15_13:54/")
parent = path.parent  # == Path("/root/LOAD/LOGS/")
parent_as_string = str(parent)  # == "/root/LOAD/LOGS/"
```

---

This is also repeatable

```
parent_of_parent = path.parent.parent  # == Path('/root/LOAD')
```